# Tkinter widgets lost information when I open a new instance of their window

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

In my real software I have a main menu (the main window) and others ones (toplevel windows) that the user can open using some widgets placed in the main one. it seems work, the main window can open the other toplevel windows, but I saw a really big issue. when I open more than one window for the same menu, all of them, except the last one, lost always the information placed in their widgets (in my case, Entry and ComboBox widgets). let's start with a simple example:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
    
        # load a "SecondWindow" object:
        self.obj=SecondWindow(self)
        
        # main window's gui:
        self.parent=Tk()
        self.parent.geometry("300x280+360+200")
        self.parent.title("main window")
        self.parent.configure(background="#f0f0f0")
        
        self.OkButton=ttk.Button(self.parent, text="open the second window", width=26, command=lambda:self.obj.GUI())
        self.OkButton.place(x=20, y=20)

        self.parent.mainloop() 
    
class SecondWindow:
    def __init__(self, mw):
        self.mw=mw
    
    def GUI(self):
        self.window=Toplevel(self.mw.parent)
        self.window.geometry("300x180+360+200")
        self.window.title("second window")
        self.window.configure(background="#f0f0f0")
            
        self.MenuSV=StringVar()
        self.MenuSV.set("test test test")
        self.MenuComboBox=ttk.Combobox(self.window, state="readonly", values=("ciao", "hola", "hello", "Salut"), textvariable=self.MenuSV)
        self.MenuComboBox.place(x=20, y=20)
        
        self.window.mainloop()

# start the program:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_gui=MainWindow()
```

this code works like my real software. before to open the main window, a SecondWindow object is loaded (his main component is the GUI function). when you open the second window for just one time (using the SeconWindow object loaded before), it's ok, no issues, but if you open another one, the first one lost the information placed in his widgets. why?

[image]

I really don't understand this weird behaviour. how can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you created only one instance of `SecondWindow()` inside `MainWindow`, so whenever `GUI()` of `SecondWindow` is executed, `self.MenuSV` will be reassigned another instance of `StringVar()`, so the previously created instance of `StringVar()` has no variable reference to it and it is garbage collected.

You can either create new instance of `SecondWindow()` whenever the button is clicked:

```py
class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
    
        # load a "SecondWindow" object:
        #self.obj=SecondWindow(self)
        
        # main window's gui:
        self.parent=Tk()
        self.parent.geometry("300x280+360+200")
        self.parent.title("main window")
        self.parent.configure(background="#f0f0f0")
        
        self.OkButton=ttk.Button(self.parent, text="open the second window", width=26,
                                 command=lambda:SecondWindow(self).GUI()) # create new instance of SecondWindow here
        self.OkButton.place(x=20, y=20)

        self.parent.mainloop()
```

---

Or keep a reference of `self.MenuSV` inside `SecondWindow`:

```py
class SecondWindow:
    def __init__(self, mw):
        self.mw=mw
    
    def GUI(self):
        self.window=Toplevel(self.mw.parent)
        self.window.geometry("300x180+360+200")
        self.window.title("second window")
        self.window.configure(background="#f0f0f0")
            
        self.MenuSV=StringVar()
        self.MenuSV.set("test test test")
        self.MenuComboBox=ttk.Combobox(self.window, state="readonly", values=("ciao", "hola", "hello", "Salut"), textvariable=self.MenuSV)
        self.MenuComboBox.place(x=20, y=20)
        self.MenuComboBox.MenuSV = self.MenuSV  # keep a reference
        
        self.window.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks acw1668! I chose your second solution and it worked, but I still don't understand why `self.MenuSV` has to change when I opena nother window. is it not an indipendent "StringVar()" object?

Comment: `self.MenuSV` is *a reference* to a `StringVar` object, not the `StringVar` object itself.